# How can i get a Mongoose custom error message?

Tags: express, validation, mongoose

So I have this mongoose schema that I want to validate

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "You Must Include A Name"],
        toLowerCase: true,
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, "Price Must Be Included"],
        min: 0
    },
  
})
const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
module.exports = Product;
```

In index.js I extended Error class and wrote this middleware

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err.name == 'CastError') next(new AppError(`This is a CastError${err.message}`, 400))
    else if (err.name == 'ValidationError') next(new AppError(err.message, 400))
    else {
        next(err)
    }
})
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log(err.msg)
    const { message = 'Something Went Wrong', status = 500 } = err
    res.status(status).send(message)
})
```

When I make a validation error i get this: **Product validation failed: price: Price Must Be Included**
or when leave both name and price empty it get:**Product validation failed: name: You Must Include A Name, price: Price Must Be Included**

I just want: "Price Must Be Included"
or: "Name must be included"
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your else if parse the err.message down to the message you want to emit and use that.  Here is one way to parse it using string split on colon

```
else if (err.name == 'ValidationError') {
  const messageParts = err.message.split(':');
  next(new AppError(messageParts[2], 400)
} else ...
```